# Oauth2 authorization code flow: where do I store authorization code?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

Good day! I am trying to implement my own authorization server using oauth2 standards. Upon reading into its specifications on authorization code flow, a 3rd party application requesting for API access needs an authorization code from the authorization server, which will then be used to exchange for an access token. My question is, once I generate an authorization code from my authorization server, by concept, where do I store it so that when a client app requests an exchange for access token, I can verify that the authorization code is valid?

Comment: Isn't the code being generated Just-in-Time when the client app makes the request for the parent app? I have not seen the code being stored as such in advance for apps to retrieve it later on.

Comment: Yes, it is generated just-in-time. My concern really is just how can my authorization server verify that the authorization code used to exchange for an access token is valid. Whether it needs to be stored somewhere or not, I actually don't know. But a particular specification that says authorization code should only be good for one use, hints me that it shouldn't be stored. But I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: That's correct, it is not to be stored at all per specification. It is to be used for 1 time per application and then discarded. So, every time a child app requests the authorization, flow would create the auth code and pass to the child app which would then exchange it for the access token.

Comment: So how then, will my authorization server verify if the authorization code passed by the client app is valid?

Comment: I think you will need some kind of cache for that (redis?). Or you could only save in in runtime. Generally you should retrieve the code quickly from the client after generating it.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure, that only the client whom you issued the code can use it, and delete it after it has been used

Answer (score 3):

You can store the code anywhere you want - in your server memory (as an object in a map), in a database or in any other safe storage. If your server is just a single application (having just one RAM), you can store the codes in memory if you don't mind losing them during application restarts. But if you want to run multiple instances of your application (e.g. in Kubernetes) or server is composed of multiple applications, you will need to use some external storage (database, Hazelcast, Redis).

With the code, you will need to keep metadata such as client_id, validity, [PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) attributes (code_challenge_method, code_challenge) and such. When you receive a request to your token endpoint wanting to exchange the code for tokens, you need to find the code in your storage, compare the relevant metadata (client_id, PKCE code_verifier, client_secret) and issue tokens.

But you should keep the code with a timestamp saying when the tokens were issued. And you should be able to find what tokens were issued from the code. Because if you receive another `/token` exchange request with the same code, you should invalidate all the tokens issued - the code was probably stolen.

It's good to read [OAuth2 Security RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics) for all the considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global data structure `map` and map the client_id to the auth codes and delete them after the access token is exchanged, this is a very simple a valid solution as long as it is properly implemented and the auth code and deleted correctly.

Since the exchange happens directly, you don't need to worry about the heap filling up since the auth code is created and deleted in a very short period of time making space. Say 1000 users log in every minute, a data structure of 1000 elements is very acceptable in most cases assuming there is a timeout of the exchange of 1 min (which should be the case)